# Texmaker: Searching all files

Tags: texmaker, mac, spelling

I would like to search in my whole source code, which contains a lot  of input-commands.

For example, I would like to search for \mathbb{N}, and replace it with \mathbb{M} in every file.

I also would like to spell-check all files at once.

I'm using Texmaker 4.5 on a Mac.

Comment: I don't know of any such in build batch-tools in TexMaker/Studio. I use linux as my OS and there is a simple command to search `foo` and replace it with `bar` in multiple .tex files: `sed -i 's/foo/bar/g' *.tex` maybe there is something like that for the other OS too...

Comment: If you're under Windows, `notepad++` can do that in all open files, and also in all the files of  a folder (including subfolders).

Comment: I'm using a Mac (updated Question)

Comment: I dont know how to search 'whole source code', but, one document, first, you select the word(s) which you want replace, then you can type `ctrl + R`, and choose replace all.

Comment: Thanks @Bernard
Your answer reminded my, that I got a great searching-tool, that can at least do the search part. (Since I would have replaced it manually anyway, this is great) (There are also other tool, that can search and replace in multiple files)

Comment: @audiophiel FYI the sed command is available on Mac as well